# merging multiple Int16Array

Tags: javascript, html

i am manipulating wav data in chunks , and everytime the worker returns a chunk as Int16Array, I want to merge all these into a single Int16Array which i would convert to final .wav file, so what is the efficient way for doing this?

is what I have done correct?

```
        ...
    var offset=0;
    var finalArray;
    worker.onmessage = function (e) {
        //e.data is the Int16Array
        if(!finalArray){        
            finalArray=e.data;
            offset=e.data.byteLength;
        }else{
            finalArray.set(e.data,offset);
            offset+=e.data.byteLength;
        }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory to fit both chunks, and then place the contents in that new array.

So, what you are doing is correct. If performance is an issue, you could be smart on which array to seek in offsets, but that's probably more trouble than its worth.

Comment: the problem is I am not sure as to what would be the final length of finalArray, so i cannot set a default length.